# angular catch keyword error on YUI minification

Tags: javascript, angularjs, yui

I have used the then and catch for my ajax call:

```
        try {
            ServiceData.getProductDetails(product).then(function(data) {
                    $scope.productDetails = data;
                })
**Line 445**                    .catch(function(fallback) {
                        $scope.buildProductDetails(product);
                    });
            } catch (err) {
                $scope.buildProductDetails(product);
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

On minification I get error that invalid catch block:

```
[ERROR] 445:27:missing name after . operator
[ERROR] 446:32:syntax error
[ERROR] 447:22:'try' without 'catch' or 'finally'
[ERROR] 448:20:missing ; before statement
[ERROR] 449:24:syntax error
[ERROR] 451:9:missing ] after element list
[ERROR] 452:5:syntax error
[ERROR] 453:2:syntax error
```

How do I tell YUI that .catch is the angular catch not the traditional try catch.
Pls help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.catch` method in AngularJS's `$q` (used by `$http`) is not the same as the `catch` statement of a `try { ...} catch { ...` block. That `try {` you are using is wrong, you shouldn't be using it.

*Just to make things clearer:*

"`catch(errorCallback)` – shorthand for `promise.then(null, errorCallback)`". It's the function callend when you call [reject](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#reject) inside the promise. (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-promise-api)

The `try ... catch` statement is a builtin JavaScript mechanism. The code inside the `catch` block is executed when you use `throw 'some exception'` inside the `try` block.

The AngularJS documentation for `reject` is pretty clear: "When comparing deferreds/promises to the familiar behavior of try/catch/throw, think of reject as the throw keyword in JavaScript." Though, just to be safe, I'd add "**Although conceptually similar, don't mix them up!**" to that :)